# pass column name in data.table using variable in a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I want to loop through a selection of columns from a data table and summarise my data by that column. I'm able to pass the column name in as a variable using `quote()` and `eval()` and it works fine

```
library("data.table")

dt <- data.table(x=c("b","b","b","a","a","c","c"), y = c("x","y","z","x","y","z","x"), v=rnorm(7))

splitBy <- quote(y)

sdt <- dt[,list(meanV = mean(v)),by=. (eval(splitBy))]
```

However when I try to put that into a loop like this

```
library("data.table")

dt <- data.table(x=c("b","b","b","a","a","c","c"), y = c("x","y","z","x","y","z","x"), v=rnorm(7))

myList <- c("x","y")

for (i in myList){

  splitBy <- quote(i)
  sdt <- dt[,list(meanV = mean(v)),by=. (eval(splitBy))]

}
```

it doesn't work. I know that split By evaluates correctly as `x` or `y`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In this instance, using by=i will suffice: `sdt <- dt[, list(meanV = mean(v)), by=i]`

Comment: Even better is probably `sdtList <- lapply(myList, function(i) dt[,list(meanV = mean(v)),by=i])`.

Comment: Use `c` instead of `.` and you can just pass a character vector: `splitBy <- "y"; sdt <- dt[, list(meanV = mean(v)), by = c(splitBy)]`